# Can access modifiers be completely replaced with programming to interfaces?

Tags: java, programming-languages, interfaces, development-methodologies, access-modifiers

If we program to interfaces various parts of the implementation can be effectively hidden.  We can define multiple interfaces for a single implementation and use them as needed, instead of 4 fixed levels (public, protected, package protected, private).

From this point of view Access modifiers seems redundant and limited. From my experience, they also tend to promote bad practices and bad design decisions compared to interface-managed access.
The private access modifier seems especially contra-productive on methods because it limits their testability.

Is there some case for access modifiers that can't be handled better in a more systematic way using interfaces?

Comment: Problems can always be "handled in a different way". The alternative to access modifiers would be more overheads in terms of the explicit definition of more interfaces (and some system for controlling access to these). And the amount of overhead a company like (say) Microsoft is willing to bear in writing general-purpose software and APIs for the entire world, is different from the amount of overhead a business with one staff member will bear in making use of Microsoft's platform.

Comment: You still need `private`, to be able to hide implementation details from things that subclass you, unless you remove subclassing.

Comment: @Caleth good point but I would consider subclassing/class inheritance an antipattern. (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Composition_over_inheritance)

Comment: "The private access modifier seems especially contra-productive" `private` is the *most important* access modifier. You don't need to directly test private code. You test the *reachable* private code, as part of testing the public interface, and it's perfectly fine for any *unreachable* private code to have undefined behaviour.

Comment: But I suppose that anything not mentioned in an interface is implicitly `private` in your scheme

Comment: `From this point of view Access modifiers seems redundant and limited`. Well, beneath the interface there's an implementation which might have several components working together, each of which with limited access to each the other. The alternative is interface implementations with hundreds LoC. So basically, most of the modifiers focus on keeping encapsulation within a boundary. Boundaries within boundaries.

Comment: "Composition over inheritance" says to *prefer* composition, not to never do inheritance or consider subclassing an antipattern. Sure, subclassing shouldn't be overused as a way to model things (in the "if your only tool is a hammer, everything looks like a nail" fashion), but it can work in tandem with composition and interfaces.

Comment: Don't forget that you can cast an interface to a concrete class, which would allow you to access non-interface members. I really need to stress the importance of @Caleth's comment about `private` being the most important access modifier. See [data/information hiding](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Information_hiding) and [encapsulation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Encapsulation_(computer_programming)). Casting an interface to a class allows you to circumvent data hiding and encapsulation, but access modifiers enforce this at the compiler level.

Comment: @OndrejBozek: subclassing is **not** an antipattern - where did you get this nonsense from? Subclassing in cases where *composition could be used sensibly instead* is an antipattern.

Comment: @GregBurghardt, interpreting things within the OP's terms, I assume there would be no facility to cast to a class, and no such thing as a "non-interface member".

Comment: If subclassing is an antipattern to you then maybe you should avoid all OOP entirely.

Answer (score 3):

Access modifiers and interfaces serve different purposes in an object-oriented language. An interface is used in cases where you desire loose coupling and polymorphism. Access modifiers are used to promote [data hiding](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Information_hiding) and [encapsulation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Encapsulation_(computer_programming)) at the compiler level.

The critical flaw with using interfaces for data hiding and encapsulation is revealed when down-casting an interface to a concrete class. Most OO languages allow you to do this:

```
public interface IFoo
{
    void Something();
}

public class Foo : IFoo
{
    public void Something() { }
    public void DoNotCallMe() { }
}

IFoo foo = new Foo();

foo.Something(); // <-- "allowed" by the interface

Foo bar = (Foo)foo; // <-- cast IFoo down to concrete Foo

bar.DoNotCallMe(); // <-- this compiles and executes at runtime
```

This allows code to circumvent restrictions provided by the interface if you are willing to risk a runtime exception. Most programmers, since it compiles, will ignore the runtime risk, because they got something to work.

Access modifiers prevent unauthorized access at compile time. If you mark a method or field `private`, even down-casting from an interface to a concrete class prevents careless or malicious programmers from using something inappropriately.

---

A word of caution about languages that support class reflection. You can still circumvent private access modifiers in many languages, but it is a much bigger pain than simply down-casting an object.

Solution: trust that a developer who is using class reflection has a valid use case for doing so (see Object-Relational Mappers). If you do not trust the developer, do not hire them.

Also, a word of caution when using compilers that allow you to turn off access modifiers. Access modifiers are not magic. They are enforced by the compiler, so if you tell the compiler to not enforce this restriction, then you can circumvent those restrictions.

Solution: never compile your application using a compiler you do not trust, and never have someone compile your application if you do not trust them.

Comment: Good point, but this type cast is antipattern and would shine bright in review.   
It could be prohibited by encapsulating Impl class in Proxy class which implements only interface methods and forwards them to Impl.

Comment: @OndrejBozek: introducing a proxy class instead of properly using access modifiers would also be an anti-pattern.

Comment: @OndrejBozek, in Swift such casts are safe and expected. You write “if let bar = foo as? Foo”. as? Means a cast that can fail and returns nil on failure, “if let” assigns an optional value to a non-optional that can only be used within the If statement. Very common pattern. Especially when you have a protocol (interface) “Any” which can be literally anything, so you _must_ cast it.

Answer (score 2):

It really helps to understand what the keyword `interface` really is. It’s a hack. A retrofit. Created because they finally figured out how to support multiple inheritance but couldn’t make it work with existing classes. The venders wouldn’t allow a change that would require existing, working, tested Java byte code to be recompiled. So rather than classes that support multiple inheritance we got the keyword `interface`.

It started with Java and spread to every language that follows Java. And then it stopped. Because it’s not what you do if you have a choice.

If you have a choice you design your language to support multiple inheritance right in your classes. No need for the `interface` keyword at all.

With this in mind, understand that “program to an interface” simply means to access only what is meant to be publicly available. A keyword `interface` isn’t required. Just an understanding of what is meant to be public.

And since the understanding is the important thing here you don’t need access modifiers either. Just some way to signal what the public interface is.

And that brings me to Python. In Python you don’t have keyword interfaces. You don’t have access modifiers. You have a convention that says if it starts with an underscore it’s private. And by that we mean you’re on your own if you code against this. We might change it at any time. No whining if we do.

No keywords. No modifiers. Just a clear signal that you’re poking around in the employees only part of the store.

So yeah, access modifiers can be replaced. We can do without a lot of that stuff just with some clear communication.

Comment: Kudos for getting to the heart of the matter, and clearly stating what the saying actually means.

Comment: A complementary view to Python, there's C++'s concepts, static checks which apply to a type at the point of use, rather than keyword `interface` applied at point of declaration.

Comment: @Caleth yes and C++ has multiple inheritance right in it’s classes. But C++ does have access modifiers. Easier to make the point with Python.

Comment: I strongly oppose to `interface` being a hack, retrofit, or some kind of attempt to multiple inheritance. On the contrary, there would better be no inheritance at all in Java, working just with `interfaces`(similar to e.g. Go lang). Interfaces are much more useful than inheritance. Inheritance is a code smell, even more so multiple.

Comment: @OndrejBozek it’s not clear what you mean. Are you disagreeing with my historical recounting or with any attempt to support inheritance?

Comment: I would be interested to see a citation for interfaces being a hack; I would assert that they are wonderful whatever their origins. That aside, this answer seems to be saying "you don't need any language features for hiding", which I don't think is really addressing the spirit of the question. Existing Python tooling recognises 'conventions' like the underscore prefix and tries to provide the same useability that is baked into languages where hiding is a feature: for a convention like that to be useful it has to saturate, so it essentially is a language feature (with poor/inconsistent support)

Comment: To try to make my comment less incomprehensible and to explain my -1, you seem to me (and my interpretation could be way off) to be saying "access modifiers can be replaced with access modifiers without uniform tooling support" and dismiss interfaces (which are at the heart of the question) entirely with some comments about multiple inheritance that are irrelevant to the question. I can see that there may be a frame-challenge in here (and I suspect we'd agree that the OP is missing the point of encapsulation slightly), but the whole answer reads rather like a tangential rant to me.

Comment: So you are saying the "interface" concept in Java was a predecessor of multiple inheritance? Sorry, but I don't think that's historically correct, MI in C++ and Smalltalk is definitely older. And I think Java language designers choose *intentionally* to allow implementation inheritance only with a single class, and only "interface inheritance" with multiple interfaces, since the experiences of MI in C++ showed there were way too many possibilities to use MI wrongly.

Comment: @DocBrown I’m certainly not saying Java was the first to solve MI. I’m saying they locked themselves into a class model that prevented them from solving it with proper abstract classes. I’d rather not know if I’m talking to an interface. But in Java you can’t switch a type from one to the other without recompiling every client that knows of the type. They didn’t know how to do that and solve the diamond problem. So they stuck us with interfaces. Which force people to create interfaces prematurely because they can’t switch later without a big recompile. Much bigger problem than MI in C++.

Comment: Here's a good explanation of the diamond problem in C++[=](https://www.makeuseof.com/what-is-diamond-problem-in-cpp/)

Comment: @VisualMelon The point of my rant was to drive home the idea that the phrase "program to an interface" isn't about interface as in the keyword. It's about the predating concept of interface as in the API.

Comment: @candied_orange aaaaah, that makes a lot more sense now as essentially a direct response to the title: that was completely lost on me. Perhaps the OP needs to qualify their question and title since this doesn't seem to be what they are getting at.